# What is the fastest way to store and access single bits in an N dimensional array of bits in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, x86, bit

I have a code in which I need to read and write single bits of data from and to a large array of bits (several megabytes in total) in a random fashion. Something similar to playing battleships with a N dimensional array.
I suspect that a compact array would be faster, as it would keep some of the array in cache. On the other hand I know access time to an element of an array available as an array object is equivalent to access through a compile-time pointer value and element access time in a typical implementation of a std::vector is the same as element access through a run-time pointer value (slower). And I have no idea how bitsets and bitfields fit in all this.
I don't need this code to be portable, just very fast (x86).

Comment: So you want a [bit array (a.k.a. bitmap)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array)? Those are very common, for example for filesystems where you can have a bitmap of allocated blocks. When you know these terms, you could search for algorithms more easily. Also, unless you have a high-end workstation/server CPU you won't be able to fit "several megabytes" in the cache at once anyway, random access will most definitely cause cache-misses and reloads.

Comment: What is the distribution of the bits?

Comment: most probably Rayleigh distribution along each axis, but I haven't done any proper analysis about that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single answer for that as it will depend on the processor architecture (and the compiler).

That said, a bit array is quite fast. You simply create it as a array of `int`s and then access the bits by selecting the correct `int` and extracts the correct bit. It will be compact, fast as long as your `int` has a power of two number of bits (32, 64 etc) - otherwise you might have to do a tradeof between compactness and speed (for example on a 36 bit processor you could chose speed and use only 32 bits per int).

The code in the compact case becomes `(p[idx / BITS_PER_INT] >> (idx % BITS_PER_INT))`. For the fast case where `BITS_PER_INT = 2 << SHIFT` this is the same as `(p[idx >> SHIFT] >> (idx & (BITS_PER_INT-1))) & 1`.

If you require more control of the storage of the data you could customize the layout to comply with your requirements (although if portability is no issue, this is also probably not an issue).

Again as it's also implementation specific what's fastest I should probably mention `std::vector<bool>` which although not guaranteed to be as fast or compact as possible it's quite likely that it at least is one of them and probably a good trade-off between them if required.

Comment: Or use `std::vector<bool>`  which is a specialized template

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That could be used if you don't require a guarantee that the data is stored compactly.

Comment: I don't need it to be compact for any specific reason. This question is 100% about speed. I only suspect that compact data would give me less cache misses and faster execution.

Comment: @Andreas If cache is your concern you have to take care so that the cache doesn't get evicted before next access, that is you have to also consider what's being done between the accesses to the bit array.

Comment: @Andreas What I meant was that there may be other occasions where memory will be accessed (and possibly evict data from cache). For example there's local variables, function calls and so on. And of course your data will come from somewhere so you access memory there as well.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into how element access translates to assembler code I went ahead and implemented my own bit addressing method.
I used

```
char array[n][n]...[n/8];
```

and created a lookup table

```
char lookup[8]={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};
```

and split the last array index in two using the 8 least significant bits to access the lookup table and used an binary or | for writing bits and for reading I used binary and & to mask the bit and bitshifted by the same  index I used to address the lookup table.
the read part:

```
bool result=(bool)(array[x][y]...[z>>8]&lookup[(char)(z&255)])>>((char)(z&255))
```

the write part:

```
array[x][y]...[z>>8] |= lookup[(char)(z&255)] //writes 1
```

I am quite pleased with the performance and this should compile in to near minimal assembler code, but I don't have any solid proof.